# Custom button on Edit Page

Tags: custom-button, edit

If I have an object like Account , Contact , or a custom object , is it possible to add a custom button (or custom Action) on the Edit page ?

Comment: What does this have to do with the Communities feature?

Answer (score 2):

[Custom Buttons](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=defining_custom_links.htm&type=0) and [Object-Specific Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_overview_object_specific.htm&type=0) do not appear on Object Record Pages when in Edit mode. They are intended to be used from Detail or other Pages to automate the creation of new records, opening detail pages in edit mode with pre-defined values populated, opening records for editing in some context, auto-updating records, or performing other types of actions such as opening an external web link.

An Edit page is already in "Edit mode", so clicking a button or action from within one could easily create conflicts with the controller for the object. Standard buttons for the object's controller (or a custom page controller that's been substituted) need to be respected and observed in those situations. That isn't to say that a custom button defined for use on a custom page to work within the confines of the custom controller couldn't be utilized while editing the page; provided it called a method contained in the page controller.

Additional Help references you may want to review are [Custom Button and Link Samples](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=links_useful_custom_buttons.htm&type=0) and [Actions Best Practices](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_best_practices.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=206.17).

Comment: According to your answer I understand that we can not add a button in an edit page like Edit Contact for example.
So , Is there an another option to be able to modify the fields in edit mode like enter or replace data in the fields of an edit page ?

Comment: If a user has the correct permissions, they can edit the fields manually when in Edit mode. Can you give a more specific example of what you want the button to do? It may be that you need to use a `BeforeUpdate` trigger.

Comment: Yes exactly, I have a trigger Before Create to Encrypt fields  that the administrator will have chosen. And I want to add a trigger Before Update or a simple button (Decrypt on the edit page), in order to decrypt the data before edit them.
**So when the simple user click on edit page I would like to display the true value and not the encrypted value.**

Comment: It sounds as though your real issue is that your users don't have permissions to view encrypted data. You'd be violated the principles behind encryption security if you decrypted it for them. This is something you don't want to do. Either give them permissions to view encrypted data, or don't allow them to edit those fields.

Comment: No, the simple user can encrypt/decrypt the data , he is the owner of this data. The administrator will choose for the users of the org (with an interface only for him) which of the fields will be encrypted.

Comment: So my question is : **Is it a way to add a button on the edit page that will decrypt the fields and replace them** , So in this way the user could be edit the true value (not the encrypted value) , Of couse when the user will click on save it will be a trigger berfore update in order to encrypt before saving but it is not the point for now.

Comment: Then I'm not certain I understand you question. If the owner of the data encrypts it and other users have permission to view encrypted data, are you saying you wanting to decrypt data for other users where they don't have the proper permissions via sharing?

Comment: We are leaving the subject ,It is not the question , Is it a way to add a button in an edit page (Like I added a button on detail page ). or is it impossible ?

Comment: Buttons can't be added to Edit pages unless you've created a custom Detail Page & controller with methods to replace the standard Detail Page.